# html / CSS Align image within div, with main image being background

Tags: html, css

The issue I'm having is a bit different than that I've found thus far the goal is to make an HTML page in which each background img div will be one page, thus when printing it will be clean.
Here is what the code looks like.

```css
.thirdBackgroundPage {
  background-image: url("images/firstBackgroundPage.jpeg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.icobp {
  height: 75%;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="thirdBackgroundPage">
 <img class="icobp" src="images/imageCenterOfBackgroundPage.jpeg" />
</div>
```

With this said, there are other <, div class, so the first image is on the third page for example, where right now with this, it brings the image in the center top, however, I need it dead center or bottom.

I've tested a few things, but to no avail. Tried setting it up within a table, but this does not work either. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Background-position: center center; ? You mean?.. not sure of the question....please elaborate...

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate the printing you have to use @media print so you can control which one you just want to print. If you needed to center a spcific element you have to use this code @media print as well.And display:none for the other one you dont want to be printed. sometimes you have to use display:block o display:inline-block to get it to work as well. Hope this will help your issue.

```css
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}
@media print {
  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
.thirdBackgroundPage{
  vertical-align:middle;
  align-items:center;
  page-break-before:avoid;
  page-break-after:avoid;
  page-break-inside:avoid;}
}
```

```html
<div class="thirdBackgroundPage">
 <img class="icobp" src="images/imageCenterOfBackgroundPage.jpeg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey there, So i undersand what you try to do with this, however this would not work for what im trying to do. as it would simply apply for the one variable and is not something that can work, thanks for the input. also you missed one ";" after the page-break-after:avoid

Comment: You're are probably trying to find a more dynamic printing. I am not sure what you are aiming but I know for a fact that this codes can be very dynamic and manipulate any sort of pages you want to print. Let me know, I added more that might help you on whatever you are trying to print.

Answer (score 1):

You already had other suggestions to better center your div inside the container, anyway that's mine. In the snippet below I just added a css rule that will add some style attribute to the container so that its content will be correctly centered both vertically and horizontally via `display:flex;`

<del>Since you talk about printing html pages, I want to warn you that html/css are still not suitable for that since there are no tools to address publishing details like page number or page size. You can control the content size but it will never be accurate and I could experience myself that i will become inaccurate starting from page 30 maybe..I can't remember in details.</del>

Anyway I considered that div `.thirdBackgroundPage` as filling an A4 page so I gave it those size in mm. Let me know if I got it wrong.

```css
.thirdBackgroundPage {
  background-image: url("images/firstBackgroundPage.jpeg");
  /*height: 100%;*/
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
}

/*Style attributes I added to the list container*/
.thirdBackgroundPage {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
}

.icobp {
  /*height: 75%;*/
  /*Needed to change this to give the pic a size despite the url fake*/
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="thirdBackgroundPage">
 <img class="icobp" src="images/imageCenterOfBackgroundPage.jpeg" />
</div>
```

Comment: I am more interested in what you crossed off then what you wrote - I dont need more then 10 pages that are properly aligned, the issue is that the query you provided , ive played with something like this - but unfortunately it doesnt work. As the size that i've set 

```  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}```

Determines the size of background, setting items relative to the class thirdBackgroundPage is something that im struggling with, as if i could make it relative .

Comment: As such it can't work with what you provided.

Comment: The passage I crossed was wrong because CSS3 added target print with media queries making my statement wrong nowadays. That 100% height was pointless indeed and I commented that part in my css on top of my words about impaginating contents for printing on A4. By the way I'm afraid I can't be any more helpful. I hope you'll find a way to solve your problem.